# VBA Code using Windows API for colorising Textbox selection

Tags: vba, windows, api, richtextbox

Hello VBA & Windows API experts ! I have the following code which is supposed to set the color of the current selected text in a rich text Textbox, but it works only partially. For example, it puts the whole text in Blue instead of just the selection. Can anyone spot where the problem can be ? I am using VBA 7 - 64 bits - Windows 10

Form module

`Private Sub cmdButton_Click() 'Selected Text in Blue
Dim lngHandle As Long
lngHandle = fhWnd(Me.txtITMrichtxt)
RTBSetTextColor lngHandle, vbBlue
End Sub`

Code Module

```
Option explicit
Public Enum ATTDEFINI
  ATTUNDEF = -3
  ATTDEFAULT = -2
End Enum
Private Type CHARFORMAT2
  cbSize As Long
  dwMask As Long
  dwEffects As Long
  yHeight As Long
  yOffset As Long
  crTextColor As OLE_COLOR
  bCharSet As Byte
  bPitchAndFamily As Byte
  szFaceName As String * LF_FACESIZE
  wWeight As Integer
  sSpacing As Integer
  crBackColor As OLE_COLOR
  lcid As Long
  dwReserved As Long
  sStyle As Integer
  wKerning As Integer
  bUnderLineType As Byte
  bAnimation As Byte
  bRevAuthor As Byte
  bReserved1 As Byte
End Type
Public Enum RTBC_FLAGS 'CharFormat (SCF_) flags for EM_SETCHARFORMAT message.
  RTBC_DEFAULT = 0
  RTBC_SELECTION = 1
  RTBC_WORD = 2      'Combine with RTBC_SELECTION!
  RTBC_ALL = 4
End Enum
Private Const WM_USER As Long = &H400
Private Const EM_SETCHARFORMAT = WM_USER + 68
Private Const CFM_COLOR As Long = &H40000000  '<-> Membre de la structure CHARFORMAT2 ou Attribut de dwEffects
Private Const CFE_AUTOCOLOR = CFM_COLOR
Declare PtrSafe Function apiGetFocus Lib "user32" Alias "GetFocus" () As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageWLng Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Any) As LongPtr

Function fhWnd(iaControl As Control) As LongPtr
On Error Resume Next
iaControl.SetFocus
If Err Then
  fhWnd = 0
Else
  fhWnd = apiGetFocus
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Sub RTBSetTextColor(ByVal ilngHWND As LongPtr, Optional ByVal ilngTextColor As OLE_COLOR = -1, _
                           Optional ByVal Scope As RTBC_FLAGS = RTBC_SELECTION)
Dim cf2Colors As CHARFORMAT2

With cf2Colors
  .cbSize = LenB(cf2Colors)
  .dwMask = CFM_COLOR
  If ilngTextColor = ATTDEFAULT Then
    .dwEffects = CFE_AUTOCOLOR
  Else
    .dwEffects = 0
    .crTextColor = ilngTextColor
  End If
End With
SendMessageWLng ilngHWND, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, Scope, VarPtr(cf2Colors)
End Sub
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile , you need to post the full code,  LF_FACESIZE not declared.

Comment: Where did u get this code ?

Comment: I made up this code myself a few years ago from pieces of code I had found on Internet, when I making tests with a rich text control + a Ink Edit control on an Excel form. I think it worked (it was windows 7 for sure, and a previous version of Office, I forget which).

Comment: I would like to post a acddb file (500KB) but I cannot find how to upload a file into the discussion